# Выделение товара и добавление его в корзину

Tags: html, javascript

Вот есть такой [скрипт](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/display-grid.html).
Он выделяет блоки.
А вот сама [корзина](http://cart.99points.info/).
Помогите сделать так: чтобы выделяешь товар, после выделения появляется кнопка "Добавить в корзину", если выделено, а если просто нажать, то сразу чтобы добавлялся в корзину.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так демо пример так и работает, когда просто кликаешь, то он отправляет товар в корзину, а зачем тут нужны jquery-ui не понятно, неужели пользователь будеть мышкой выделять область товаров, которые он хочет добавить за один раз или зажимать ctrl, чтобы выделить все товары а только потом нажать добавить?